# counting blocked users' entries in a title

Tags: python, django, database, orm

Block Model:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    blocker= models.OneToOneField("auth.user",on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name="blocker")
    blocked=  models.ManyToManyField("auth.user",blank= True, symmetrical=False)
```

Title Model:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    first_author = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150, unique = True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title_url= models.CharField(max_length = 150)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

Entry Model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey("titles.title", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.user", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000,)

    def get_likes(self):
        return self.likes.likers.count()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

I am trying to get the count of a title's entries that belong to users blocked by "request.user".

I tried the query below but it didn't work:

```
blocked_count= Entry.objects.filter(user__blocker__blocked=request.user,title=title.title,created_date__gte=date_from).count
```

I know the one below would work if "blocked" was one to one field and "blocker" was many to many field:

```
blocked_count= Entry.objects.filter(user__blocked__blocker=request.user,title=title.title,created_date__gte=date_from).count
```

But I do not want to change the model. So I need to find a solution for my current situation.

Comment: Then it should be `blocked_count= Entry.objects.filter(user__block__blocker=request.user,title=title.title,created_date__gte=date_from).count()` But nevertheless the model is not good, likely you should implemented as two `ForeignKey`s, not a 1-1 and m2m.

Comment: Thank you once again Willem. Could you tell me why double ForeignKey is better?

Comment: because with an m2m, you make two new tables, one for the `Block` model, and one for the m2m, the `Block` model would then be "unnecessary", since it is just something extra of the `User` model. You thus make queries more complicates (and it will result in extra JOINs), and thus more work for the db.

Comment: Thanks again, have a great day!